# Default share using phonegap for Android and ios

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

For my application I need to implement the 'share' for android and IOS which is similar like share in gallery ,Is there any plugin for the same?
Please suggest.
thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think you will need a plugin. you can implement your own code!

Comment: looking for the same: for the last 2 days.. 
check this link, https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share , let me know how is it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use phonegap share plugin . check this link

- Android link : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share
- IOS : https://github.com/bfcam/phonegap-ios-social-plugin
- For more Plugins Please check this git : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins